# Rails 4 - Looping Through Checkboxes and Inserting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, checkbox

Using Ruby on Rails 4, I'm trying to loop through my student list, and insert their ID's into the attendances table via a checkbox.

I'm getting the following error:

> No route matches {:action=>"mark_attendance",
>   :controller=>"attendance"} missing required keys: [:student_id,
>   :attendance_id]

My files:

**routes.rb**

```
  resources :static
  resources :student do 
    resources :attendance
  end

  devise_for :users
  root :to => "static#index"
```

**student_controller.rb**

```
class StudentController < ApplicationController
    def index 
        @students = Student.all
    end

    def show 
        @student = Student.find(params[:id])
    end

    def create
        @student = Student.new(student_params)
        respond_to do |format|
            if @student.save
                format.html { redirect_to @student, notice: 'Student was successfully added.' }
                format.js
                format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @student }
            else
                format.html { render action: 'new' }
                format.json { render json: @student.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
    end

    def student_params
        params.require(:event).permit(:name, :contact, :balance)
    end 
end
```

**student.rb**

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :attendances
  attr_accessible :name, :contact, :balance
end
```

**attendance_controller.rb**

```
class AttendanceController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @student = Student.new(attendee_params)
        respond_to do |format|
            if @student.save
                format.html { redirect_to @student, notice: 'Students were added successfully.' }
                format.js
                format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @student }
            else
                format.html { render action: 'new' }
                format.json { render json: @student.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
    end

    def mark_attendance

    end

    def attendee_params
        params.require(:event).permit(:student_id, :date)
    end 
end
```

**attendance.rb**

```
class Attendance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student
  attr_accessible :student_id, :date
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="content marketing">
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                    <tr>
                        <th>&nbsp;</th>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Contact</th>
                        <th>Balance</th>
                        <th style="width: 8%">&nbsp;</th>
                    </tr>
                    <% form_tag student_attendance_mark_attendance_path do %>
                        <% @students.each do |s| %>
                        <tr>
                            <td><%= check_box_tag "student_ids[]", s.id %></td>
                            <td><%= s.id %></td>
                            <td><%= s.name %></td>
                            <td><%= s.contact %></td>
                            <td><%= number_to_currency(s.balance) %></td>
                            <td><%= link_to "View", student_path(s.id), :class => "btn btn-primary" %></td>
                        </tr>
                        <% end %>
                    <% end %>
                </table>
            </div><!-- End Table Responsive -->
        </div><!-- End col-md-8 -->
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    </div>
</div><!-- End Row -->
```

I would love to know what the error is or how I would be able to do this using checkboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a path helper that needs parameters passed to it:

```
<% form_tag student_attendance_mark_attendance_path do %>
```

It apparently needs a Student, and Attendance.  If you can't supply that, then you have a design problem.

Comment: Should be: `<%= form_tag...`?

Comment: Yeah that'll be a problem too. :)

Comment: It looks like this seems to have solved it: 
As per vinodadhikary's answer, I changed it to:
`<%= form_tag mark_attendance_attendance_index_path do %>`

I also changed the routes file to:

`resources :attendance do
    post 'mark_attendance', on: :collection
  end`
`

Thanks!